# When do nonnegative integer matrices satisfying some conditions have integral eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $X_1,X_2$ be non-degenerate integer matrices with nonnegative entries. The Perron-Frobenius theorem (technically, an extension of P-F theorem) says that all such matrices $A$ have a positive real eigenvalue $\lambda_{FP}(A)$ which is larger than or equal to the magnitude of all of the other eigenvalues.

Suppose that we know that $\lambda_{FP}(X_1)+\lambda_{FP}(X_2) \in \mathbb{Z}$. There is a theorem in the book Tensor Categories by Etingof, et al which says that this implies that $\lambda_{FP}(X_1)\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\lambda_{FP}(X_2)\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Does anyone know how to prove this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. I'm not sure if the book author has made a mistake or you've misunderstood his/her words, but here is a counterexample:
$$
Y=\pmatrix{1&1&1\\ 1&1&1\\ 1&1&1},\ X_1=\pmatrix{1&1&0\\ 1&1&1\\ 1&1&1}.
$$
The Perron eigenvalue of $Y$ is $3$, but the eigenvalues of $X_1$ are $\frac12(3\pm\sqrt{5})$ and zero.

It is quite obvious that the statement is very implausible. Note that for any $n\times n$ nonnegative integer matrix $X_1$, there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $X_1<Y=kE$ entrywise, where $E$ denotes the all-one matrix. Since $\rho(kE)=kn$ is an integer, had the statement in question been true, it would imply that every nonnegative integer matrix has an integer Perron eigenvalue.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to simplify my actual question but I clearly made a mistake. I want all matrices to be non-degenerate and also $\lambda_{FP}(X_1)+\lambda_{FP}(X_2)\in\mathbb Z$.  I have edited it to reflect this.